# Show unmatched documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How do you include unmatched items in your results on elasticsearch?

For example,

I have a list that somewhat looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_index": "products",
        "_type": "71",
        "_id": "556637aed75a1334f69db5d7",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "product_id": "556637aed75a1334f69db5d7",
            "categories": [
                28
            ],
            "tags": ["shirts"]
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "products",
        "_type": "71",
        "_id": "556637aed75a1334f69db5d2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "product_id": "556637aed75a1334f69db5d2",
            "categories": [
                27
            ],
            "tags": []
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "products",
        "_type": "71",
        "_id": "556637aed75a1334f69db5e4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "product_id": "556637aed75a1334f69db5e4",
            "categories": [
                26
            ],
            "tags": [
                "shoes"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "products",
        "_type": "71",
        "_id": "556637aed75a1334f69db5dd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "product_id": "556637aed75a1334f69db5dd",
            "categories": [
                23
            ],
            "tags": []
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to get a result that shows matched documents first and unmatched documents next.

If my query looked something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "tags": [
                "shorts",
                "shoes"
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [ "_score" ]
}
```

I would get a list of only the items that have either `shoes` or `shorts` tags.

I would like to also show the unmatched items after the matched ones.

Also, I would like to add `categories` in my search query. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need `sort` on `_score`. By default, the sorting of the results is done on score.

Second, there is no such thing as displaying the "unmatched" docs. You need to define your own rule of matching "the unmatched". In my opinion, you need a `match_all`.

Third, I suggest using a `bool` where every condition you have (match on tags, match on categories, `match_all` - to match the "unmatched" docs) should be placed in a `should`. Every condition will add something to the score. This means, the more conditions match, the greater the score. If `tags` and `categories` don't match, the score for the remaining docs (the ones match `match_all`) will be low, so they will be at the end of the list.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "tags": [
              "shorts",
              "shoes"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "categories": [26,23]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was this simple. Thanks, Andrei, I've been trying to figure this out for the past 2 days.

Comment: :-) no worries, I'm glad I was able to help you.

Comment: Btw, is it possible to boost the relevance for the `categories`? I tried adding `{ boost:2 }` after `terms` but that gave me an error. EDIT: sorry not an error, but rather didn't give me different results.

Comment: `{
          "terms": {
            "categories": [
              26,
              23
            ],
            "boost": 2.0
          }
        }` and score changes, yes.

Comment: That didn't change the score, though. Maybe it's my dataset? It shows the exact same results. What happens is tags seem to have more weight than categories.

Comment: It changes the score, but slightly. At least in my tests, it did. The score is not that straight forward to compute. ES uses the [tf/idf](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html) and, as such, it depends on your data.

Comment: Alright then, I'll figure something else out. This already helped me out BIG TIME. Thanks, again.